# translate on an background image without interrupting the content inside it

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to redesign a website and I have a problem. I want to use `transform` on a `background-image` without interrupting the content inside it

```
<div style="background-image: url(example.png)"> <!-- want to use transform on this image -->
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1> <!-- without interrupt this -->
</div>
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do to the background image?

Comment: @imvain2 I want to try to zoom on hover this background image, but all answers on the internet were also interrupt the content inside it

Comment: Just set `background-size:100%` and then on hover set `background-size:150%` or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying the background image to the parent div (I've named it `.headingWrapper` in the below snippet), why don't you make use of [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) (`::before` or `::after`)?

Below, I add an image to the `before` pseudo-element, then hovering changes the image in some way (I've simply scaled the image, but other styling is possible)

```css
.headingWrapper::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://cataas.com/cat");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.headingWrapper:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="headingWrapper">
  <!-- want to use transform on this image -->
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  <!-- without interrupt this -->
</div>
```

Comment: Not bad! Although I think I'd found a solution, but this also should work and even more configuration. Thanks!